# Accessing 2D array elements using pointer arithmetic in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have this code in which I've been trying to figure out a doubt on pointer,array combination.

```
int main()
{
  int s[4][2] = {
    {1234,56},
    {1212,13},
    {1434,80},
    {1312,78}
  };
  printf("%d\n",s[2]);
  printf("%d\n",*s[2]);
  printf("%d\n",s+2);
  printf("%d\n",*(s+2));
  return 0;
}
```

**And the doubt is:**
           Even though s[2] and (s+2) refer to the same address, why does *(s[2]) prints the value (i.e., 1434 ) but *(s+2) prints the same address what (s+2) has printed. Isn't *(s+2) mean value at address of 3rd 1D array(i.e., s[2][0])?

Comment: "Even though s[2] and (s+2) refer to the same address, " - they do not!

Comment: To begin with you have *undefined behavior* because you use the wrong format for the wrong type. `s[2]` is an array that decays to a pointer, `*(s + 2)` is the exact same as `s[2]` and as such also is a pointer, and `s + 2` is also a pointer. For pointers you need to use the `"%p"` format.

Comment: 918019136
1434
918019136
918019136
This is what the output is. Are you sure they are not pointing to the same address.? @WeatherVane

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude . I've changed %d to %p (other than *s[2] because it's obvious that it returns a value) , but the output is same except for the fact that it is printing the addresses in hexadecimal format now. :D

Comment: So they do: your code confused me by a) adding a size to part of the variable: the `+2` is two of *what* size is not immediately clear, b) using the wrong types. If you have 64 bit pointers, the code would definitely not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets take a look at how your array look in memory:

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| s[0][0] | s[0][1] | s[1][0] | s[1][1] | s[2][0] | s[2][1] | s[3][0] | s[3][1] |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
^         ^         ^                                                           ^
|         |         |                                                           |
&s[0][0]  &s[0][1]  &s[1][1]                                                    |
|                   |                                                           |
&s[0]               &s[1]                                                       |
|                   |                                                           |
s[0]                s[1]                                                        |
|                   |                                                           |
s                   s+1                                                         |
|                                                                               |
&s                                                                              &s+1
```

Now lets take `s[0][0]`, you have *five* possible pointers that can point to that location:

1. `&s[0][0]`. This is of type `int *`.
2. `&s[0]`. This is of type `int (*)[2]`.
3. `s[0]`. This will decay to a pointer to the first element in `s[0]`, and is equal to 1.
4. `s`. This will decay to a pointer to the first element in `s`, and is equal to 2.
5. `&s`. A pointer to the array, of type `int (*)[4][2]`.

As you can see you can have many different pointers to the exact same location, but they can mean different things which makes a whole lot of difference semantically.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, but it still itches me that if s+1 points to s[1][0], then why does *(s+1) doesn't print value at that address?

Comment: @ManikantaAnkam Because `s + 1` is a *pointer* to an *array*, it's type is `int (*)[2]`. When you dereference it like `*(s + 1)` you get something which is of type `int[2]`, i.e. you get the *array* `s + 1` is pointing to. And that decays to a *pointer* of type `int *`. To get the value you need *another* dereference: `**(s + 1)`, which is equal to `s[1][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

s[2] and (s+2) link to the same address as you can see with a simple printf.
Then you have an undefined behavior because `%d` refers to an integer but `s[2]`, `s+2` and `*(s+2)` are pointer and you have to use `%p` that refers a pointer.
Here is your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int s[4][2] = {
        {1234,56},
        {1212,13},
        {1434,80},
        {1312,78}
    };
    printf("%p\n",s[2]);
    printf("%d\n",*s[2]);
    printf("%p\n",s+2);
    printf("%p\n",*(s+2));
    return 0;
}
```

No, `*(s+2)` isn't mean `s[2][0]` it's only the logical address of the second element of s. You have to use `*(s[2])` for `s[2][0]`.

Comment: Thankyou :D, you clarified most of the confusion but what is logical address mean.?

Comment: The logical address is the address at which s reside inside the process space.

Answer (score 0):

> Even though s[2] and (s+2) refer to the same address, why does *(s[2]) prints the value (i.e., 1434 ) but *(s+2) prints the same address what (s+2) has printed. Isn't *(s+2) mean value at address of 3rd 1D array(i.e., s[2][0])?

`s`, apart from the array name, is also a *pointer* to the first element of the array, which is the first line.

In general, keep in mind that :

```
s[i][j]
```

is equivalent to :

```
*(s[i] + j)
```

as well as to :

```
*(*(s + i) + j)
```

So `s[i]` is equivalent to `*(s+i)` and to `*(*(s+i) + 0)`.

Based on these, you can see that :

- `s[2]` is the same as `*(s+2)` and indicates *the third element of your array*. This is the address of the third line of your array, exactly the same with the address of the first element of the third line of your array.
- `*(s[2])` means `*(*(s+2))`, and indicates the ***content of the third element of your array***. This is the content of the first element of the third line of your array (i.e., `1434`).

If you want to print `s[2][0]`, this is equivalent to `*(*(s+2) + 0)` or simply `*(*s[2])`.

Comment: everything what you've said is clear to me and I've tried implementing that to pass a 2D array to a function. Here is what my code looks like, display(s,4,2) is the function call in main, and the implementation is void display(int *q,int row,int col), inside here in two for loops I've tried to display each element using printf("%d", *(*(q+i)+j)), but it doesn't work for some reason, but on searching, I've found *(q+i\*col+j) will work. Can you please explain me why the earlier one didn't work.?

Comment: @ManikantaAnkam because in the declaration of function `display` you state that you expect the first argument as `int *q` but you pass `s`, which is equivalent to `int **`.