# 2D Array decaying to pointer in C

Tags: arrays, pointers, 2d

This is an extended question from the answer by "Some programmer dude" in this forum. 
[Accessing 2D array elements using pointer arithmetic in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44284362/accessing-2d-array-elements-using-pointer-arithmetic-in-c)

To quote the answerer,

> 1. &s[0][0]. This is of type int *.
> 2. &s[0]. This is of type int (*)[2].
> 3. s[0]. This will decay to a pointer to the first element in s[0], and is equal to 1.
> 4. s. This will decay to a pointer to the first element in s, and is equal to 2.
> 5. &s. A pointer to the array, of type int (*)[4][2].

I don't get why 3 equals 1 and 4 equals 2?

I thought 3 equals 2 and 4 equals 5.

For example, putting s[0] will give the address of s[0] since it's an array, hence s[0] = &s[0].

Comment: You are basically stating that "the pointer to a quantity is equal to said quality". Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at your 2D array and consider the types of the various variables you've asked about:

```
int s[4][2] = {
    {1234,56},
    {1212,13},
    {1434,80},
    {1312,78}
  };
```

Now:

- `s` is a 2D array of ints.
- `s[0]`, `s[1]`, etc. are arrays of int.

Your question states:

> putting s[0] will give the address of s[0] since it's an array, hence
>   s[0] = &s[0]

This is not correct. When used in an expression, the name of an array decays to a pointer to the *first element* of the array.  What is the first element of `s`? It is the entire array `s[0]`.

Since `s[0]` is an *array*, it is equivalent to the address of its first element. What is the first element of the array `s[0]`? It is the int `s[0][0]`. So since the value of the array name `s[0]` when used in an expression is equivalent to the address of the first element of the array, i.e., to `s[0][0]`, we have:

```
s[0] == &s[0][0]
```

This is why (3) in the answer you have quoted is equivalent to (1).

Similarly, `s` is equivalent to `&s[0]`. When used in an expression, the array name `s` decays to a pointer to the entire array `s[0]`; as a pointer to an array of two `int` elements, its type is `int (*) [2]`. Its value is the address of `&s[0]`, i.e., the address of the entire array (not just of its first element). This is why (4) is equivalent to (2).

As "Some programmer dude" showed in the diagram in his answer to your original question, these various pointers might point to the same location in memory, but semantically they are quite different.

Hope this helps!